# Failed to execute child process permission denied while executing a Python program after giving it the necessary permissions

Tags: permissions, python

Even after I gave my Python program execute permission and after adding the necessary PATH to the my python (`#!/usr/bin python`) I am still getting this error message.

After correcting the shebang a new error came up with saying No such file or directory even tho I launched it out of the directory.

I tried giving it permissions via `chmod` and the graphical way.

To clear things up its not about executing that file that works fine via terminal but I want to execute it as a executable in my directory.

Also i already changed the settings of Files already to execute python and not to display it

The code I want to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

# Voreinstellungen
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
screen.fill((200,200,20))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders oder auch nicht")


try:
    picture = pygame.image.load("/home/lasse/Documents/Python programme/Pygame space invader/grafik.bmp").convert_alpha()
except:
    print("Kein Bild")
    sys.exit(1)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (55, 40))

playerpos = player.get_rect()

x = 0
y = 0

schleife = True
while schleife == True:
    screen.fill((200,200,20))
    screen.blit(player, playerpos)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            schleife = 0
            break
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                schleife = 0
                break
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y = 0
    playerpos = playerpos.move(x,y)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: If your shebang line is really as you show, then it lacks a slash! `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: was as shown but after correcting no change

Comment: if the Python script complains about not being able to execute a child process, then the permissions problem is probably about something the code is trying to do, not about the permissions of the program itself. If that's the case, we can't help unless you show your code!

Comment: the code just is a test doing (print("Hello"))

Comment: Does `type python` give you `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: indeed it does.

Comment: How do you expect us to help when you don't show your code? It's like saying "Oops, I got a syntax error. Please do guesswork and tell me how to fix it.".   Try `./your_script.py`, i.e. prepend `./`. Unlike Windows, the current directory (`.`) is usually not part of the PATH in Linux for security reasons so you have to explicitely write `./script.py`.

Comment: sorry new to linux mb i forgot that

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your Python script should be as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

In order to execute the Python script by double-clicking the file, open the *Files* file browser -> *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Behavior* tab -> under the **Executable Text Files** heading click the radio button to the left of where it says *Run executable text files when they are opened* .

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70600/discussion-on-answer-by-karel-failed-to-execute-child-process-permission-denied).